# Where did I go wrong in my proof that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $\sqrt{2} < a_n$ with $(a_n)$ being a particular recursive sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing, induction, solution-verification, recursion

I am in Introduction to Abstract Math, and I have taken Calculus 1, Linear Algebra, and Discrete Math. I got stuck with an apparent contradiction in my proof and wanted to know where I messed up:

Consider the sequence $(a_n)$ defined recursively by:
$$a_1 = 3, \:\:\:\:\:\:\: a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{1}{a_n} \:\:\:\:\:\:\: (n \geq 1).$$
Prove that $\sqrt{2}$ is a lower bound for $(a_n)$.

This can be rewritten as: Prove for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $\sqrt{2} < a_n$, which we can prove with strong induction.

Base Step
Check for $n=1$.

$$a_1 = 3 > \sqrt{2}$$

Check for $n=2$.

$$a_2 = \frac{a_1}{2} + \frac{1}{a_1} = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{11}{6} > \sqrt{2}$$.

Therefore, the statement holds true for $n=1, n=2$.

Inductive Step
Assume that $a_n > \sqrt{2}$ for $1 \leq n \leq k$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. Prove $a_{k+1} > \sqrt{2}$.

$$a_k = \frac{a_{k-1}}{2} + \frac{1}{a_{k-1}} > \sqrt{2}$$
$$a_{k+1} = \frac{a_k}{2} + \frac{1}{a_k}$$
$$a_{k+1} = \frac{\frac{a_{k-1}}{2} + \frac{1}{a_{k-1}}}{2} + \frac{1}{\frac{a_{k-1}}{2} + \frac{1}{a_{k-1}}}$$
$$a_{k+1} = \frac{2a_{k-1}}{a_{k-1}^2 + 2}+\frac{a_{k-1}}{4}+\frac{1}{2a_{k-1}}$$
$$a_{k+1} = \frac{2a_{k-1}}{a_{k-1}^2 + 2}+\frac{1}{2}(\frac{a_{k-1}}{2}+\frac{1}{a_{k-1}})$$
$$a_{k+1} = \frac{2a_{k-1}}{a_{k-1}^2 + 2}+\frac{1}{2}(a_k)$$
$$a_{k+1} = (\frac{2a_{k-1}}{a_{k-1}^2 + 2} \times \frac{1}{a_k})a_k+\frac{1}{2}(a_k)$$
$$a_{k+1} = a_k (\frac{2a_{k-1}}{a_{k-1}^2 + 2} \times (\frac{2}{a_{k-1}}+a_{k-1}) +\frac{1}{2})$$

Here's where I got stuck. I plugged it into Wolfram Alpha to do the algebra for that step and see if there was equivalent forms, and I saw that what was in the parenthesis was equal to $\frac{5}{2}$, which gives
$$a_{k+1} = \frac{5a_{k}}{2}$$
which doesn't make sense as the sequence would be increasing way too fast.

Where did I mess up in my proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another approach, let $f(x)=\frac x2+\frac 1x$ for $x>0$.  It is easy to confirm that $$f(x)=\sqrt 2\iff x=\sqrt 2$$

As $f(x)$ is clearly continuous for all $x>0$ we see that $x>\sqrt 2$ must then imply that $f(x)>\sqrt 2$ and we are done.

Comment: I don't think I can do that that easily though because the sequence is discrete. Unless I'm misremembering something?

Comment: Your sequence consists of particular values of my function $f(x)$.  The property I describe holds for all $x>\sqrt 2$ so therefore it must hold for your particular values of $x$.

Comment: To stress:  my claim is more general, hence stronger, than what you need.  In principle, there might have been some $c>\sqrt 2$ for which $f(c)<\sqrt 2$ without violating your claim (as $c$ might never come up as one of your $a_n$).  Happily, the more general claim is true and, as you see, fairly easy to prove.

Comment: Oh my god I spent a whole day on a proof that was like three lines long, I think that would work well for my purpose.

Comment: Wouldn't I also need to prove that $f(x)$ is constantly decreasing?

Comment: Your post didn't ask for "decreasing" but that it easily shown:  We want to prove that $x>f(x)$ for all $x>\sqrt 2$.  But the only solution to $x=f(x)$ is $x=\sqrt 2$ (remember, we have $x>0$).  Since $x>f(x)$ for $x=3$, say, we must have $x>f(x)$ for all $x>\sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't really "mess up". You just got stuck because this approach leads nowhere. However, there is certainly something wrong in what you typed in Wolfram Alpha.

You could do this, assuming $a_n>0$:

$$a_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}=\frac{a_n}{2}+\frac{1}{a_n}-\sqrt{2}\\=\frac{1}{2}\left(a_n+\frac{2}{a_n}-2\sqrt{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{a_n}-\sqrt{\frac{2}{a_n}}\right)^2\ge0$$

And there is equality only if $a_n=\sqrt{2}$. Given that $a_1=3>\sqrt{2}$, you get that $a_n>\sqrt{2}$ for all $n\ge1$.

Comment: Would you be able to explain that a little bit more in depth? I'm still confused.

Comment: @CalypsoRivers Sure. Where are you confused? To prove that $u>v$, I write $u−v$ as the square of a number, up to a positive coefficient. It's a usual trick with this sequence, by the way.